# Sequelize – order by values presence

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model that includes fields like `price_from`, `price_to` and `created_at`.

Right now I'm querying it like this:

```
Model.findAll({ order: [['created_at', 'DESC']] });
```

I would like to add another order query, so records that do not have both `price_from` and `price_to` would be returned at the end, but without sorting by those prices.

Is there a way it can be achieved in Sequelize?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a CASE WHEN statement using `sequelize.literal`, as the following:

```
Model.findAll({ order: [
    ['created_at', 'DESC'],
    [sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN price_from IS NULL AND price_to IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'), 'DESC']
] });
```

May your fields are `0` or empty so, you may adapt the `CASE` comparison.